# Select a column with only one mapping in a Many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a many-to-many table with product and tag columns. How do I query for " Give me the list of products which have only one of these tags in their mapping.

Input : '3'  (This corresponds to tagid columns in Mappings table)
Output Expected : 4  (This corresponds to productid column value int he last row of Mappings. please note productid 1 is not returned because 1 has other mappings (tag 1 and tag 2) associated with it).

```html
-- Table: Product
+---------+-----------+
| productid | name      |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | HTC       |
|       2 | Nokia     |
|       3 | Samsung   |
|       4 | Motorolla |
+---------+-----------+

-- Table: Mappings
+------+-----------+
| tagid| productid |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |       1   |
|    1 |       2   |
|    2 |       1   |
|    2 |       3   |
|    3 |       1   |
|    3 |       4   |
+------+-----------+

-- Table: Tags
+------+-------+
| tagid  | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | blue   |
|    2 | black  |
|    3 | pink   |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Edit your query and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the `having` clause?

```
select producctid
from mappings m
group by productid
having count(*) = 1;
```

If you also want the tag id, you can get that easily:

```
select producctid, max(tagid) as tagid
from mappings m
group by productid
having count(*) = 1;
```

Because there is only one tag in `mapping`, the `max()` will return that tag.

EDIT:

If you want to specify a single mapping, then you can use:

```
select producctid, max(tagid) as tagid
from mappings m
group by productid
having count(*) = 1 and max(tagid) = 3;
```

Comment: What if the product has a tagid smaller than 3. Will the query work? max only gives the max value. isn't it?

Comment: @yagnasri . . . The requirement is that there be only one tag.  Hence, the `max()` of one row is the value from that row.